# What is different between const primary = red[500]; // #F44336 const accent = red['A200']; // #F44336?

Tags: material-ui

Three way below is to get color:

`const primary = red[500]; // #F44336`

`const accent = purple['A200']; // #E040FB`

`const accent = purple.A200; // #E040FB` (alternative method)

But I don't know what is different between them?
and Which one should we use?

Answer (score 0):

> Three way below is to get color [...] what is different between them?

**If "them" means the methods to get a color...**

The methods to get a color (`purple['A200']` vs `purple.A200`) are equivalent in result, as you pointed out. It stems from the fact that properties in JavaScript object can be accessed by key (`[]`) and vice versa. However, properties can't start with a number, so `red.500` won't work.

**If "them" means the color values...**

The values are defined here https://material.io/design/color/#tools-for-picking-colors.

> Which one should we use?

**If "one" refers to the color...**

You should use colors that fit the narrative of your app, that were picked by your app's graphic or UI designer, or find out yourself, which color works best *for you*.

Start by reading [this](https://material.io/design/color) to see how color works in Material Design.

**If "one" refers to the method...**

Use whichever works for you. It's your code. It produces the same result in both cases. I probably would pick the `[]` syntax because it works both with normal colors and accent colors and I'd like my code to be consistent.